# deployment of scrapy selenium project

Tags: python, selenium, deployment, scrapy

I am new to scrapping.
I have a scrapy spider that uses **selenium** for items interaction 
I tried to run it on a digitalocean droplet but it fails to runs the phantomjs driver all the time like it's kinda blocked raising exception:

> BadStatusLine: ''

and any other webdrivers are unstable according to the display issue and xvfb.
raising irregularly

> Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.

is there any idea what should i do where where i can deploy it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for my problem with phantomjs it was solved by reinstalling it and increasing the droplet memory .. and for the other message with the other browsers I used "xvfb-run -a" it was a temporary solution but it worked ...